# Pinterest style css layout without plugins 

Tags: jquery, css, layout

You can see the jsfiddle link for my code 
How to put the style like pinterest without plugins
Here you can see a square Node.js in Diagram I want that to have postion down the left side .

http://jsfiddle.net/madhu131313/HaxwT/[image: See this link]

I know there are plugins to make a layout like 
I know there are pluginss and frameworks
http://gumbyframework.com/

http://masonry.desandro.com/

But I want the make it simple without plugins or Frameworks

Comment: What are you asking for? Someone to to your work, or do you have a problem that is blocking you..? Pls make the question fit the Q&A format

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that using css alone.

Comment: Without Masonry, Isotope or the tiles plugin, you can't have that kind of responsive layout with CSS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those plug-ins have been created to do what you are trying to do because there is no simple solution I'm afraid.

Either use one of the plug-ins such as Masonry or simply code it yourself in plain html/css by placing your items in columns.

Obviously creating it in columns means it won't work dynamically etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

It works really well for me and it was easy to implement. Though, it doesn't keep things in order and I'm not sure how to fix that. It's worth checking out I think.